# css to align title and summary

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the title and the summary below it.
http://pligg.marsgibson.info/story.php?title=when-i-was-responsible-for-all-the-pcs-in-a-large-studio-i-learned-that-i-needed-to-carry-a-recovery-disk-at-all-times-

see the screenshot 
http://i50.tinypic.com/2akb4m0.jpg

suggest css to align according to the screenshot

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a personal code writing service. (Hint: `padding-left` or `margin-left` on the right element will do what you want)

Comment: Post a small example of the code in question here if you want help.

Comment: Are you looking for `text-align: justify`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `margin` and `padding` to align them correctly, something like:

```
.title{
   margin-left: 46px;
}
.summary{
   padding: 5px 80px;
}
```